# Custom export script for blender

Tags: python-3.x, blender

I'm trying to write a custom script to export the objects on my scene with their center of rotation. Here's what my algorithm looks like to get the center of rotation:
1- Select object using its name then call
2- Snap cursor to object(center)
3- Get mouse coordinates
4- Write mouse coordinates

```
import bpy

sce = bpy.context.scene
ob_list = sce.objects

path = 'C:\\Users\\bestc\\Dropbox\\NetBeansProjects\\MoonlightWanderer\\res\\Character\\player.dat'

# Now copy the coordinate of the mouse as center of rotation
try:
    outfile = open(path, 'w')
    for ob in ob_list:
        if ob.name != "Camera" and ob.name != "Lamp":
            ob.select = True
            bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()

            mouseX, mouseY, mouseZ = bpy.ops.view3d.cursor_location
            # write object name, coords, center of rotation and rotation followed by a newline
            outfile.write( "%s\n" % (ob.name))

            x, y, z = ob.location # unpack the ob.loc tuple for printing
            x2, y2, z2 = ob.rotation_euler # unpack the ob.rot tuple for printing
            outfile.write( "%f %f %f %f %f\n" % (y, z, mouseY, mouseZ, y2) )

    #outfile.close()

except Exception as e:
    print ("Oh no! something went wrong:", e)

else:
    if outfile: outfile.close()
    print("done writing")`enter code here`
```

Obviously the problem is step 2 and 3 but I can't figure out how to snap cursor to object and get cursor coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the script from blenders text editor you will get context errors when you try to run most operators, but the info that you want can be retrieved without using operators.

If you want the 3DCursor location you can find it in [`scene.cursor_location`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.cursor_location)

If you have snapped the cursor to the object, then the cursor location will be equal to the object location, which is at [`object.location`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.location), as snapping the cursor will make the cursor give the same values you can just use the object location and not have to snap the cursor to it. What you're code is actually doing (if it was working) is to snap the cursor to the selected objects, which positions it at the median point between all selected objects. As you loop through your objects, you are selecting each object, but you aren't de-selecting them, so each iteration adds another object to the selection which offsets the cursor to a different position each time, but only to the first object's location if all objects were un-selected at the start.

The objects rotation is stored as radians so you may want to `import math` and use [`math.degrees()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#angular-conversion)

Also as an object can have any name you should find it more accurate to test the object type to choose what to export.

```
for ob in ob_list:
    if ob.type != "CAMERA" and ob.type != "LAMP":

        mouseX, mouseY, mouseZ = sce.cursor_location
        # write object name, coords, center of rotation and rotation followed by a newline
        outfile.write( "%s\n" % (ob.name))

        x, y, z = ob.location # unpack the ob.loc tuple for printing
        x2, y2, z2 = ob.rotation_euler # unpack the ob.rot tuple for printing
        outfile.write( "%f %f %f %f %f\n" % (y, z, mouseY, mouseZ, y2) )
```

Comment: Indeed there's no need to snap to cursor since the location of the object refers to its center. Thanks for your time :) !